# Priority among conflicting attributes

Tags: html, css

How is the priority determined when conflicting attributes are specified directly or through css?

In this example, the `display : none` specified through css seems to be overriding the `display : inline-block` that is directly specified for `id=1`, so that element becomes visible.

```
<style>
.invisible{
    display : none
}​​
</style>
<div id=1 class="invisible" style="display:inline-block">Hello World</div>
```

In the following example, where I have two conflicting class specifications,

```
<style>
.invisible{
    display : none
}​​
.visible{
    display : inline-block
}​​
</style>
<div id=1 class="visible invisible">Hello World</div>
```

the  `display : inline-block` specified through `.visible` class seems to be overriding `display : none` specified through `.invisible` class.

What are the rules that determine the priority in these cases?

Comment: Both `visible` and `invisible` specify `display: none`. Guess this should be fixed to reflect the actual rule contents before going further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, in example one, your code is wrong...It's not display="inline-block"..it's

```
<div id=1 class="invisible" style="display: inline-block;">Hello World</div>
```

inline styles always take precedence over style sheets.  but because it was written incorrectly, the style sheet took over.

In example two, the display block wins because it is declared after display:none.  Browsers read code from top to bottom, so the last value you declare for a property wins (well unless you use !important tags).  And again, inline styles always win.  There are more priority rules, but that's all you need for your example.

Comment: I just realized that. Thanks. I fixed it. Your answer was just what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

OK, for CSS rules, the notion of *[specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity)* determines which rule(s) take precedence (which is important for the case when they specify same-named properties.) If rules specifying the same CSS property have the same specificity, the latest rule specified in the stylesheet(s) contributes the property value to the computed style.

Comment: Thanks too. I read your link, and the conclusion seems to be what kdub wrote.